# How to switch on the mouse over effect of a button programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a problem with the buttons in wpf. If I move my mouse over the button, it becomes the default light blue colour, but I have an image in the button, so the image hides while the mouse is there.

I've seen some solution for this, but they were made in the XAML code. I created my buttons programmatically so it doesn't work. And the last pushed button always flashes also if I don't have my cursor on it. The problem is the same. So I need the C# code not the xaml code.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

The flashing button and the blue highlight color are part of the button's default style and to change it you'll need to override the default style. I'd suggest creating you're style in XAML and then assigning it programatically. You can get the default button style [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) and then see [this post](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Setting_Styles_Programmatically) on how to set the style programmatically.

**Update:**
It seems to work for me and here is what I did:

Create the button problematically in the back code and set the style:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(@"\path\to\image.png");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);

    BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitMapImage.BeginInit();
    bitMapImage.StreamSource = ms;
    bitMapImage.EndInit();

    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = bitMapImage;
    image.Height = 100;

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Height = 200;
    button.Width = 200;
    button.Content = image;
    button.Style = button.Style = (Style)FindResource("myButtonStyle");

    myGrid.Children.Add(button);
 }
```

Create the Style in the XAML by copying and pasting the button style provided by microsoft and modifying to behave how you want. To disable the mouse over effect I commented out the section `<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"> ... </VisualState>`

```
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Style copied from MSDN Button Style page -->
    <!-- Remove or comment out <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" /> -->
    <!-- Remove or comment out <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver> ... </VisualState>
    <!-- Change colors to your liking or set to Transparent to not show color -->
    ....
</Style>
```

Comment: OK. I've tried your solution, but it doesn't do what I want. The text style is changed in the button, but it becomes the same light blue color when the cursor is over it. So my Image isn't shown then.